# Count the total number of strings in object and all children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object that may contain objects (which in turn may or may not contain objects, etc to infinity), with strings thrown in, like so:

```
var obj = {
    "foo": "hello",
    "bar": "hi",
    "test": {
        "foo": "foo"
        "bar": {
            "test": "hi",
            "hello": "howdy"
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is count the number of strings in the entire `obj` object and its children. In this example, the correct answer would be 5.

The numerous topics about counting keys in objects on this site all suggest either a loop with `.hasOwnProperty` or the new `Object.keys(obj)` way of things, but neither of these are recursive, and both of them count the child objects themselves.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create recursive function that will loop nested objects and return count.

```js
var obj = {
  "foo": "hello",
  "bar": "hi",
  "test": {
    "foo": "foo",
    "bar": {
      "test": "hi",
      "hello": "howdy"
    }
  }
}

function countS(data) {
  var c = 0;
  for (var i in data) {
    if (typeof data[i] == 'object') c += countS(data[i]);
    if (typeof data[i] == 'string') c += 1
  }
  return c;
}

console.log(countS(obj))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is *functional programming* style ES6 function for it:

```js
function countPrimitives(obj) {
    return +(Object(obj) !== obj) || 
           Object.keys(obj).reduce( (cnt, key) => cnt + countPrimitives(obj[key]), 0 );
}
var obj = {
    "foo": "hello",
    "bar": "hi",
    "test": {
        "foo": "foo",
        "bar": {
            "test": "hi",
            "hello": "howdy"
        }
    }
};

console.log(countPrimitives(obj));
```

In fact this will also count other primitive values, including numbers and booleans, ...: anything that is not a nested object.

Comment: If we're being ES6ish about it, you can use `Object.values`.

Comment: `Object.values` is not part of ES6, but in the draft for the next EcmaScript version.

Comment: Do you know I hadn't realised that. (It's probably not much different as it would probably need transpiling anyway!)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with iterating over the keys and checking for Object.

```js
function getCount(object) {   
    return Object.keys(object).reduce(function (r, k) {
        return r + (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object' ? getCount(object[k]) : 1);
    }, 0);
}

var obj = { foo: "hello", bar: "hi", test: { foo: "foo", bar: { test: "hi", hello: "howdy" } } },
    count = getCount(obj);

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop with either of the methods you mentioned.

Something like this:

```js
var obj = {
    "foo": "hello",
    "bar": "hi",
    "test": {
        "foo": "foo",
        "bar": {
            "test": "hi",
            "hello": "howdy"
        }
    }
}

function count_strings(obj) {
  var count = 0;
  
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  for (var i=0, l=keys.length; i<l; i++) {
    if (typeof obj[keys[i]] === 'object') {
      count += count_strings(obj[keys[i]]);
    } else if (typeof obj[keys[i]] === 'string') {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
  
document.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = count_strings(obj);
```

```html
<div class="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is 50 cent of mine too.

```
function checkString(str){
  var count = 0;
  if(typeof str  === 'string'){
    return 1;
  }
  Object.keys(str).forEach(function(v){
    console.log(str[v]);
    if(typeof str[v] === 'object') count = count + checkString(str[v])
    else count ++;
  })
  return count;
}

var obj = {
    "foo": "hello",
    "bar": "hi",
    "test": {
        "foo": "foo"
        "bar": {
            "test": "hi",
            "hello": "howdy"
        }
    }
};
console.log(checkString(obj));
```